# Big Query for fetching Distinct Date and also Max of the Unique Count

Tags: google-bigquery

I have same date twice by i have different Unique Count and Hour. I want to take Max count of Unique and Hour and Distinct Date.

Can some one help ?

ex:

```
Day 2018-08-11 00:00:00 UTC 12  1950

Day 2018-08-11 18:00:67 UTC 7   86
```

So now I need a single date with Max of Unique Count?

Answer (score 0):

Your question is a little tricky to understand, but I assume you want to return the maximum value for each distinct date. You can do that by using a GROUP BY like so:

```
WITH `myTest` as (
SELECT date "2018-08-11" myDate, time "00:00:00" myTime, "UTC" myTimeZone, 8979 myValue UNION ALL
SELECT date "2018-08-11" myDate, time "18:00:60" myTime, "UTC" myTimeZone, 1274 myValue UNION ALL
SELECT date "2018-09-13" myDate, time "17:36:40" myTime, "UTC" myTimeZone, 6342 myValue UNION ALL
SELECT date "2018-09-13" myDate, time "05:05:32" myTime, "UTC" myTimeZone, 67 myValue )

SELECT myDate, max(myValue) as Max_Value 
FROM `myTest`
GROUP BY myDate
```

You can plop this into your BigQuery editor to see it work and then shape it to match whatever date you're using.

Comment: I have lot of values so Group By doesnt help much

Comment: Can you elaborate on that and provide a larger example set? Also, if you can show what you've tried so far, it can help me help you. :)